# Why does Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(...) exit the sub?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a vb application with a listview.
I was testing and ended up with this sub for my dragover event:

```
Private Sub ListView1_DragOver(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles ListView1.DragOver
    XToolStripLabel.Text = "X:" & e.X
    YToolStripLabel.Text = "Y:" & e.Y
    Dim Insertion As Integer = GetInsertion(MousePosition, ListView1)
    SelectionTestTSlabel.Text = "SEL " & Insertion
    If CurrentlyDragging Then
        Dim gr As Graphics = ListView1.CreateGraphics
        Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(New Windows.DependencyObject(), 0) 'I know this seems like it doesn't do much
        MsgBox("") 'I actually added this later because the rest of the code did not run normally.
        Dim InsertionY As Integer = 24 + (Insertion * TestItemHeight)
        If MyLastInsPoint = Insertion Then
        Else
            ListView1.Refresh()
            gr.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Gray, 3), New Point(0, InsertionY), New Point(ListView1.Width, InsertionY))
        End If
        MyLastInsPoint = Insertion
    End If
End Sub
```

I realized that the MsgBox("") doesn't popup a message box then i spammed breakpoints on the whole sub.

The sub ran as normal but after this line,

`Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(New Windows.DependencyObject(), 0)`

the program returned to the form and did not execute the MsgBox("") line.

What's wrong with the line? The program did not even stop at the End Sub breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

**New Windows.DependencyObject()** has no children, so index 0 is not available

See the remaks on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getchild%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Call the GetChildrenCount method to determine the total number of
> child elements of a parent visual.
>
> The value of reference can
> represent either a Visual or Visual3D object, which is why the common
> base type DependencyObject is used here as a parameter type.